# how to run command from terminal while keeping terminal free?

Tags: command-line

Whenever I want to run a program (usually GUI) from terminal, but I want to keep it free for further use, I run the program like this:

```
./Programs/androidstudio 2>/dev/null >/dev/null &
```

This just works. I was wondering if this is the right way to do it, or if there's a shortcut way.

P.S: I don't need to keep the program running when I close the terminal. I use `guake` and I always keep it open.

Comment: why are you doing 2>/dev/null >/dev/null two times , may I know please. ?

Comment: One for regular outputs and the other for error outputs.

Comment: Well actually if you do something like 2>&1 would be fine , it can take care of both.

Comment: @Raja, Cool, this makes it shorter.

Comment: But this is something you really should read http://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For detached start try

```
 nohup <program> &!
```

Comment: Yeah, just found out about `nohup`. It's interesting.